# Multiple forms on one page, and to decide which form has been submitted using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, email

I have a page with multiple forms (2 forms) on that page.

There is a callup form and a contacts form in the footer of the page.

So customers may choose to just enter a phone nr and press submit in one form, or they may fill in the other form with name, email, and a message and then press submit.

I am working on a PHP mail() function to separate which form is beeing submitted, however I have forgot alot of programming over the last time, so I turn to you again in asking what to do here.

How can I in the PHP code separate which form has been submitted?

This is what I have in the php right now:

```
$type = $_POST['type'];

    if($type == 'callup'){
        $tel_nr = $_POST['tel'];

        $to     =       'info@domain.se';
        $subject    =   'Call customer';
        $message    =   'Client telephone nr is '.$tel_nr.'.';
        $message    .=  '\n';
        $message    .=  'Client signed in at this date and time: '.date('Y-m-d').' Time: '.date('H:m:s').'';

        mail($to, $subject, $message);

    }
```

Basically what I want to do is to send an email to myself when customer submits a form. But depending on which form customer submits, I want to send the corresponding email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiple names for submitting:

In your first form:

```
<input type="submit" name="address" value="Submit Address" />
```

In your second form:

```
<input type="submit" name="zipcode" value="Submit Zipcode" />
```

Then, serverside, check for the available names:

```
if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
    // ...
} else if (isset($_POST['zipcode'])) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Send each form to a different action:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <!-- phone number form -->
</form>

<form action="bar.php" method="post">
    <!-- name/email/message form -->
</form>
```

Then each PHP script would do what it needs to do for the given inputs, and redirect back to your forms page at the end. Advantage: each script only needs to worry about its own set of inputs, and you avoid big `if`s and/or `switch`es that toggle on an "action" flag.

Comment: Maybe adding a get parameter is more helpful as it would prevent to create one file per each form submit.

Comment: I would argue that having a separate PHP script to handle each form is *better*; it separates concerns (i.e. you don't have one big "handleAction.php"), and encourages a more MVC-like structure.

Comment: I also speak from experience. I've worked with code that used giant, multi-option `switch`es on an action GET parameter, and it's *not* fun to debug or extend.

Comment: Okay, that's another discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814626/php-form-processing-distributed-or-centralised -- however using two frontend-controllers is not more or less MVC than using one frontend controller so I can have sympathies for your argument but if I follow it put, it not a a pro nor contra argument. +1 for the overall suggestion anyway, any controller needs to understand the command requested, regardless how it get's passed.

Comment: Indeed it's a different argument, and each situation warrants the solution that best fits its needs. If the action switch works well in the OP's case for this question, then that's perfectly fine.

Comment: +1 I think this is the answer that makes sense.  It doesn't technically answer the question so the excepted answer is still valid, but in most cases I think you can avoid the problem all together with different actions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one form you can use a better name to identify each form. For example you can add a prefix form1_ to each input object and form2 to each second form input object. Then you can add a default value to each input object to identify the object.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add hidden field and check if that field is set and process one kind of form.
The simples way will be checking if that key exists as part of array using array_key_exist

```
if(array_key_exist("form1")){}
else if(array_key_exist("form2")){}
```